# Применить различные формулы в зависимости от диапазона значений

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть исходный DataFrame, в котором 4 столбца

```
      RATING  RATING2  RATING3  RATING4
           -        5        6        5
 18,69158879        6        9        6
 6,481481481        8        8        4
 2,727272727        9        7        7
 264,4628099        9        8        8
-38,16793893       10        9        7
```

Необходимо в зависимости от значений столбца `RATING` построить столбец `FINISH`

Если значения `RATING =[-100;0)` , то `FINISH = RATING2+RATING3+RATING4`

`RATING =[0;5)` , то `FINISH = RATING2+RATING3+2*RATING4`

`RATING =[5;10)` , то `FINISH = RATING2+RATING3+3*RATING4`

`RATING =[10;20)` , то `FINISH = RATING2+RATING3+4*RATING4`

`RATING =[20;1000)` , то `FINISH = RATING2*RATING3+RATING4`

Если же значение `-`, то на выходе оно должно таким и остаться.
В итоге должны получить нечто такое:

```
       RATING  RATING2  RATING3  RATING4 FINISH
            -        5        6        5      -
  18,69158879        6        9        6     39
  6,481481481        8        8        4     28
  2,727272727        9        7        7     30
  264,4628099        9        8        8     80
 -38,16793893       10        9        7     26
```

Comment: у вас на самом деле в столбце `RATING` строки вместо чисел??

Comment: нет, там числа!

Comment: А как же `-` и запятые вместо точек в качестве десятичного разделителя?

Comment: что возвращает `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Ну может вместо `-` там будет `Nan` , это сильно повлияет? Запятые, потому что с экселя копировал, ну там точно цифры будут

Comment: Если у вас `NaN` и числа вместо строк, то это упростит решение ;)

Comment: Там точно цифры будут, не переживайте. Это отношение двух показателей, один из них через дельту будет, поэтому первое значение занулится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [70]: df
Out[70]:
       RATING  RATING2  RATING3  RATING4
0         NaN        5        6        5
1   18.691589        6        9        6
2    6.481481        8        8        4
3    2.727273        9        7        7
4  264.462810        9        8        8
5  -38.167939       10        9        7
```

Сначала создадим столбец с номером формулы в зависимости от диапазона значений:

```
In [71]: %paste
bins = [-100, 0, 5, 10, 20, 1000]
labels = ['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5']
df['FORMULA'] = pd.cut(df['RATING'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True)
## -- End pasted text --

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
       RATING  RATING2  RATING3  RATING4 FORMULA
0         NaN        5        6        5     NaN
1   18.691589        6        9        6      F4
2    6.481481        8        8        4      F3
3    2.727273        9        7        7      F2
4  264.462810        9        8        8      F5
5  -38.167939       10        9        7      F1
```

теперь создадим вспомогательный DataFrame с результатами всех формул для всех строк:

```
In [73]: %paste
formulas = """
  F1 = RATING2+RATING3+RATING4
  F2 = RATING2+RATING3+2*RATING4
  F3 = RATING2+RATING3+3*RATING4
  F4 = RATING2+RATING3+4*RATING4
  F5 = RATING2*RATING3+RATING4
"""
x = df.eval(formulas).dropna(subset=['FORMULA'])
## -- End pasted text --

In [74]: x
Out[74]:
       RATING  RATING2  RATING3  RATING4 FORMULA  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
1   18.691589        6        9        6      F4  21  27  33  39  60
2    6.481481        8        8        4      F3  20  24  28  32  68
3    2.727273        9        7        7      F2  23  30  37  44  70
4  264.462810        9        8        8      F5  25  33  41  49  80
5  -38.167939       10        9        7      F1  26  33  40  47  97
```

выберем значения из нужного столбца воспользовавшись столбцом `FORMULA`:

```
In [75]: x['RES'] = x.lookup(x.index, x['FORMULA'])

In [76]: x
Out[76]:
       RATING  RATING2  RATING3  RATING4 FORMULA  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  RES
1   18.691589        6        9        6      F4  21  27  33  39  60   39
2    6.481481        8        8        4      F3  20  24  28  32  68   28
3    2.727273        9        7        7      F2  23  30  37  44  70   30
4  264.462810        9        8        8      F5  25  33  41  49  80   80
5  -38.167939       10        9        7      F1  26  33  40  47  97   26
```

создадим результирующий столбец в исходном DataFrame:

```
In [77]: df.loc[df['RATING'].notna(), 'RES'] = x['RES']

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
       RATING  RATING2  RATING3  RATING4 FORMULA   RES
0         NaN        5        6        5     NaN   NaN
1   18.691589        6        9        6      F4  39.0
2    6.481481        8        8        4      F3  28.0
3    2.727273        9        7        7      F2  30.0
4  264.462810        9        8        8      F5  80.0
5  -38.167939       10        9        7      F1  26.0
```

---

NOTE: строки `%paste` и `## -- End pasted text --` вводить в качестве решения не надо - это `ipython` так реагирует на ввод нескольких команд из буфера обмена.

Comment: Все получается, благодарю. А что делает эта строчка `x = df.eval(formulas).dropna()` ?

Comment: @Max, создаёт вспомогательный  DF `Out[74]`